# Check if instance is null or something is in it

Tags: c++, oop

I have a timer class in my C++ project, where I have these variables:

`std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime, endTime;`

I set my startTime in the constructor, but not the endTime. What I need to do is I want to check, if the endTime is present. As a Java developer, I would do that using `endtime == null` in java, but since Null doesn't really exist in C++, I need to find a way doing the same thing, but in C++. I would also like to find a general way of doing that, not particularly for this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: You've declared it, therefore it is present. It is default-constructed if you didn't explicitly tell it how to construct.

Comment: The general solution to adding "and it might be null" to an object is to wrap it in a `std::optional<T>`. Another is to assign it a special sentinel value it wouldn't normally have.

Comment: unlike Java where everything is a pointer, an object declared in c++ isn't a pointer (you make pointers with `*`). `Type obj;`means `obj` isn't null, it is an object (for the same reason `int i;` in Java can't be null). `Type *obj = nullptr;` would be null.

Comment: *"since Null doesn't really exist in C++"* Null exists in C++ as `nullptr` but it is mostly related to pointers and pointer-like objects and sometimes to objects that are designed to be nullable or empty. Most objects (like `time_point` in your case) are not compatible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I need to do is I want to check, if the endTime is present.

A `time_point` is a *value type*, not a *reference type*, so you can't compare it to `nullptr`.

However, if a `time_point` has not been assigned a value, it is default initialized to hold the clock's epoch (ie, `time_point::time_since_epoch()` returns 0).  That can be tested for, eg:

```cpp
if (endtime != std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point())
{
    // use endTime as needed...
}
```

```cpp
if (endtime.time_since_epoch() != decltype(endtime)::duration::zero())
{
    // use endTime as needed...
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/UU5CPM)

> I would also like to find a general way of doing that, not particularly for this situation.

In C++17 and later, you can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) for that, eg:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <optional>

std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime;
std::optional<decltype(startTime)> endTime;

...

if (endTime.has_value()) // or: if (endTime)
{
    // use endTime.value() as needed...
}
```

[Live Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/r1es7VB47D)